# AngularJS Module Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using Angular in combination with RequireJS.  I've defined very concise controllers that encapsulate logic specific to those modules.  One draw back I've had is I have to include all angular modules in the top most layer which couples the separate modules to the main layer.

```
// app.js
define(['angular', 'angularui'], function (angular) {
     return angular.module('phx', ['ui.bootstrap'])
});
```

Is there a way I can inject `ui.bootstrap` later when that module needs it?  Example being, main page is just login and then inside pages need angularui so on those:

```
//dashboard.js
define(['app', 'angularui', function (app) {

     // inject ui.bootstrap here? so not to couple to main module
     return app.controller('ctrl', 
          ['$scope', function ctrl($scope) {
     }];
});
```

Comment: I am strugling with similar problems. I have no answer that satisfies me fully, but you can take a look at some of my efforts [here](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) and a different approach (not from me) [here](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example above, I was able to add:

```
// app.js
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
     return angular.module('phx', [])
});

//dashboard.js
define(['app', 'angularui'], function (app) {
    app.requires.push('angularui');
});
```

BOOM!